# Draw a circled path to a node itself in tikz-cd

Tags: tikz-arrows, tikz-cd

I would like to draw a circled arrow of a node pointing to itself in a commutative diagram. What I could achieve so far looks like the following:

[image]

Is there some way to make the loops look much like a real circle?

Below is a MWE.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=large]
    C & D
    \arrow["{F}", bend left = 30, from=1-1, to=1-2]
    \arrow["{G}", bend left = 30, from=1-2, to=1-1]
    \arrow[""{name=0, anchor=center, inner sep=0}, "{G} \,\circ\, {F}", from=1-1, to=1-1, out=-145, in=145, loop, distance=4em]
    \arrow[""{name=1, anchor=center, inner sep=0}, "{F} \,\circ\, {G}", from=1-2, to=1-2, out=35, in=-35, loop, distance=4em]
    \arrow["\theta", shorten <=3pt, shorten >=3pt, Rightarrow, from=0, to=1-1]
    \arrow["\phi"', shorten <=3pt, shorten >=3pt, Rightarrow, from=1, to=1-2]
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As explained in section 3.2 of the `tikz-cd` manual, one can use `to path` to tweak paths. In order to find the appropriate start and end angle of the arc, one can measure the node with the `calc` library. The double arrows are also drawn via `to path`. These paths are horizontal by constructions. In order to preserve the edge labels, one has to add `\tikztonodes` to the argument of `to path`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\def\myradius{1.5em}
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=large]
    C & D
    \arrow["{F}", bend left = 30, from=1-1, to=1-2]
    \arrow["{G}", bend left = 30, from=1-2, to=1-1]
    \arrow["{G} \,\circ\, {F}","\mathstrut"{name=0, anchor=center, inner sep=0}, from=1-1, to=1-1,to path={%
        let \p1=($(\tikztostart.north)-(\tikztostart.south)$),\n1={scalar(asin(0.5*\y1/\myradius))} in 
        (\tikztostart.south)arc[start angle=-\n1,end angle=-360+\n1,radius=\myradius]\tikztonodes (\tikztotarget)}]
    \arrow["{F} \,\circ\, {G}","\mathstrut"{name=1, anchor=center, inner sep=0}, from=1-2, to=1-2,to path={%
    let \p1=($(\tikztostart.north)-(\tikztostart.south)$),\n1={scalar(asin(0.5*\y1/\myradius))} in 
    (\tikztostart.north)arc[start angle=180-\n1,end angle=-180+\n1,radius=\myradius]\tikztonodes (\tikztotarget)}]
    \arrow["\theta", shorten <=3pt, shorten >=3pt, Rightarrow, from=0, to=1-1, to path={(\tikztostart|-\tikztotarget) -- (\tikztotarget)\tikztonodes}]
    \arrow["\phi"', shorten <=3pt, shorten >=3pt, Rightarrow, from=1, to=1-2, to path={(\tikztostart|-\tikztotarget) -- (\tikztotarget)\tikztonodes}]
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this! However there is a minor problem: the horizontal `Rightarrow` does not appear to be "horizontal" now. When you reduce the `radius` to `1.5em` this becomes much easier to notice. Do you think there is some way to fix this?

Comment: I cannot reproduce the observation that the arrow becomes non-horizontal. However, one has to be careful to update the radius everywhere. I added a second version in which it is easier to consistently change the radius. Note also that in the original and the new codes the double arrow is drawn with `to path={(\tikztostart|-\tikztotarget) -- (\tikztotarget)}`, which is by construction horizontal.

Comment: Thank you! Sorry that earlier I didn't notice the changes in the last two lines of the code.

Comment: My bad, didn't mention it...

Comment: @Jinwen With regards to your newest question: you need a `\tikztonodes`, i.e. `(\tikztostart|-\tikztotarget) -- \tikztonodes (\tikztotarget)` instead of `(\tikztostart|-\tikztotarget) -- (\tikztotarget)`. Again my bad.

Comment: I didn't quite understand the code here but to make the horizontal line a bit higher than in your example I changed your code to `to path={(\tikztostart) -- (\tikztotarget|-\tikztostart)}`, but then if I add `\tikztonodes` as you just remarked, there would be an error `Package tikz: Cannot parse this coordinate.`.

Comment: @Jinwen You're right, I messed up the ordering. The lower code contains the changes. Will remove the upper one.

Comment: Thank you for your update! By the way, I just posted a slightly modified version as an answer below as it is too long to fit in a comment. However, as I do not quite understand the code here, I am afraid that I might have made the code unnecessarily complicated. Do you think there would be a cleaner code to achieve the result of my modified version?

Answer (score 3):

Below is a version slightly modified from the accepted answer. In the horizontal arrows, I aligned the arrow with the height of `\tikztostart` instead of `\tikztotarget` to make it higher. However, to get the ending point of the arrow correctly, I manually added a horizontal shift of 3pt to the coordinate, which seems quite ugly in the code.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=large]
    C & D
    \arrow["{F}", bend left = 30, from=1-1, to=1-2]
    \arrow["{G}", bend left = 30, from=1-2, to=1-1]
    \arrow["{G} \,\circ\, {F}","\mathstrut"{name=0, anchor=center, inner sep=0}, from=1-1, to=1-1,
        to path={let \p1=($(\tikztostart.north)-(\tikztostart.south)$),\n1={scalar(asin(0.5*\y1/1.5em))} in
            (\tikztostart.south) arc[start angle=-\n1,end angle=-360+\n1,radius=1.5em]\tikztonodes (\tikztotarget)}]
    \arrow["{F} \,\circ\, {G}","\mathstrut"{name=1, anchor=center, inner sep=0}, from=1-2, to=1-2,
        to path={let \p1=($(\tikztostart.north)-(\tikztostart.south)$),\n1={scalar(asin(0.5*\y1/1.5em))} in
            (\tikztostart.north) arc[start angle=180-\n1,end angle=-180+\n1,radius=1.5em]\tikztonodes (\tikztotarget)}]
    \arrow["\theta", shorten <=3pt, shorten >=3pt, Rightarrow, from=0, to=1-1, to path={(\tikztostart) -- ($(\tikztotarget|-\tikztostart)+(-3pt,0)$) \tikztonodes }]
    \arrow["\phi"', shorten <=3pt, shorten >=3pt, Rightarrow, from=1, to=1-2, to path={(\tikztostart) -- ($(\tikztotarget|-\tikztostart)+(3pt,0)$) \tikztonodes }]
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

TikZ-CD uses the `asymmetrical rectangle` which has its center anchor not in the real vertical center but a fixed distance (`axis_height`) above the baseline so that arrows between nodes of the same row are drawn like math mode arrows. (This also leads to them always being horizontal.)

In this code the circular segment is drawn so that it would go through the center of the start (and not touch the north or south anchor). For this the `spath3` and the `intersections` libraries are used. Doing this mathematically for any direction other than horizontal/vertical involves too much math for me to want to figure that out. Technically, the `spath3` library is only used to remove the segment of the circle that lies inside the start node, the appropriate start and end angles could have been determined from knowing the intersections points.

I've added two ways to TikZ-CD to use the `circle around rect node` style:

1. `circle = <padding>` (`<padding>` defaults to `.5ex`, roughly half the inenr seps of the nodes in a TikZ-CD)

   If padding would be zero, this determines the radius in such a way that the circle would just touch the target coordinate/node.
2. `circle to = <angle>` draws a circle around the starting coordinate that “points” in the direction `<angle>` and has diameter `circle to distance`.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, intersections, spath3}
\tikzset{
  circle around rect node/.style n args={3}{insert path={%
    % #1 = node name, #2 = angle, #3 = distance
    (#1.center) edge[
      path only, spath/save global=carn@circle,
      to path={arc[start angle={(180-(#2))}, delta angle=360, radius={(#3)/2}]}](#1)
    (#1.south west) edge[
      path only, spath/save global=carn@rect,
      to path={rectangle(\tikztotarget)}](#1.north east)
    [spath/.cd,
      split at intersections with={carn@circle}{carn@rect},
      remove components={carn@circle}{1,3},
      use=carn@circle]}}}
\tikzcdset{
  circle to distance/.initial=3em,
  circle to/.style={to path={
    [circle around rect node/.expanded={\tikztostart}{#1}
      {\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/commutative diagrams/circle to distance}}]
    \tikztonodes}},
  circle/.default=.5ex,
  circle/.style={
    execute at begin to={%
      \path[path only](\tikztostart)
        --coordinate[at end](tikzcd@circleend)(\tikztotarget);},
    to path={
      let \p{tikzcd@diff} = ($(tikzcd@circleend)-(\tikztostart)$) in
      [circle around rect node/.expanded={\tikztostart}
                                         {atan2(\y{tikzcd@diff},\x{tikzcd@diff})}
                                         {veclen(\p{tikzcd@diff})+(#1)}]
      \tikztonodes}}}
\tikzset{
  cd/.code=\tikzcdset{#1},
  cd node/.style={font=,cd=every cell,name={#1}}}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}[
  column sep=large, bend angle=30,
%  /tikz/column 1/.append style={cd={column sep=normal}},
%  /tikz/column 3/.append style={cd={column sep=normal}},
]
  G \circ F \arrow[r, "\theta", Rightarrow]
& C         \arrow[r, "F", bend left]
            \arrow[l, circle]
& D         \arrow[l, "G", bend left]
            \arrow[r, circle]
& F \circ G \arrow[l, "\phi"', Rightarrow]
\end{tikzcd}

\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=large, bend angle=30]
  C \arrow[r, "F", bend left]
    \arrow[circle to=180, "G \circ F"' cd node=GF]
    \arrow[Rightarrow, shorten <=.8ex, from=GF, "\theta"]
& D \arrow[l, "G", bend left]
    \arrow[circle to=  0, "F \circ G"' cd node=FG]
    \arrow[Rightarrow, shorten <=.8ex, from=FG, "\phi"']
\end{tikzcd}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw] (A) {A};
\foreach[count=\i] \ang in {0, 45, ..., 359}
  \draw[red!\i0!blue, circle around rect node={A}{\ang}{1cm}];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

[image]