# Tikz - how to draw a circle from one point to another?

Tags: tikz-pgf, arc

In a tikzpicture, I want to draw a circular arc that is almost all of a circle from one point to another.  I have the coordinates of the start and end points and the radius I would like, but I do *not* know where to put the center of the circle.  Naively, I expect that using draw with bend=N with N being slightly less than 360 would give the result I want, but when N exceeds 90, bend behaves as if a smaller number was given and the arc is more or less straight from the start point to the end point.  However, given the plethora of features in Tikz, I expect that there is some straightforward way to get this effect.

In my particular application, the arc starts downward from the bottom of a node, circles around and ends downward into the top of the same node.  My current best version is

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (box) at (0,-2) {$foo$};
\draw [->] (box.south)
      to [out=260,in=100,looseness=10]
      node [midway,left=0pt] {$bar$}
      (box.north);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

where "foo" is the text in the node and "bar" is a label on the arc.  But it produces an elliptical arc rather than a circular arc:

[image: Tikz output]

Comment: Do you look for a circle, or for a loop (a non-circle) ?

Comment: If you want a circular arc, use the `arc` syntax.

Comment: Drawing a true circular arc with a curve is tedious, however with `arc` it is a bit annoying to figure out where the arc should start and end, depending on how you specify the circle the arc lies on.

Comment: [Q679153](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/679153) and its answers show a few possibilites (as part of a TikZ-CD but that's not really important). If it's okay that the arc starts exactly at the bottom and the top with a given radius, this is really easy. If you want the circle the arc lies on to go through the node's center, it gets interesting. Especially if the circle doesn't go straight to the left or the right. Can you clarify how the arc is defined?

Comment: You can create an elliptical arc.  It uses a separate x and y radius and the (starting) point is given by `({\rx*cos(\t)}, {\ry*sin(\t)})` for some angle `\t`.  In fact, `\atan2(y/ry, x/rx)` for point `(x,y)`.

Answer (score 5):

If you just want to specify two points and a radius you can use the `ext.paths.arcto` library of my [`tikz-ext` package](https://ctan.org/pkg/tikz-ext).

Since there exist two circles with one radius through two points and thus four arcs, you will need to specify which arc one you want by using, in this case,  the `large` and the `clockwise` flag.

### Code

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{ext.paths.arcto}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (box) at (0,-2) {$foo$};
\draw [->] (box.260) arc to[radius=1cm, large, clockwise]
  node [midway, left] {$bar$} (box.100);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Annoyingly, I can load the library but "arc to" fails.  I suspect it's because my TeX installation is quite old.
```
! Undefined control sequence.
\tikz@do@arcB ... \fi \endgroup \pgfutil@ifxempty 
                                                  \pgf@marshal {}{\edef \tik...
l.8   node [midway, left=0pt] {$bar$} (box.100)
                                               ;
```

Answer (score 3):

Building on DraUX's answer, you can get Tikz to calculate start/end angles based on the radius.  In this case:

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (box) at (0,-2) {$foo$};
\draw [->]
 let \n1={1cm},
 \p1=($(box.north)-(box.south)$),
 \n2={asin(\y1/(2*\n1))},
 \n3={360-\n2} in
 \pgfextra{\xdef\cstart{\n3}} \pgfextra{\xdef\cend{\n2}}
 (box.south) arc (\cstart:\cend:\n1) node [midway,left=0pt] {$bar$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Here, I have used \pgfextra to make the values of \n2 and \n3 visible globally (as \cstart and \cend).  You can omit the \pgfextra's if you say "arc (\n3:\n2:\n1)".

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it by doing something like that

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (box) at (0,-2) {$foo$};
    \draw (box.south) arc (160:-160:-0.7) node [midway,left=0pt] {$bar$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

It works, but it is an ugly solve, since you have to change the start and end angles when you change the radius.

[image]

Comment: To be more exact, you have to fiddle with the start and end to match the radius (or fiddle with the radius to match the start and end).  But you can get Tikz to calculate it; see my answer.